# Loop through array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I want to code something like below in Javascript.

I have a drop down which is loaded from array as below:

```
apple 
orange
mango 
grapes
```

Now if user selects mango from dropdown then I should reset my array to:

```
mango
grapes
apple
orange
```

Comment: @ColeJohnson I vant, to suck, your knowledge..

Comment: Please show us the relevant portion of your actual HTML.

Comment: You mean bring all options below the selected options to upper ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the shift and push methods of Array inside a loop.

Eg.

```
var items = ["mango","grapes","apple"]
var selectedIndex = combo.selected.index
for( i = 0; i<selectedIndex ; i++){
items.push(items.shift())
}
combo.items = items
```

Im not a daily javascript programmer so this is just an idea.

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to change the combo box after it's originally been populated.

Comment: Thanks for reply but with your code  if i select grapes, it will just give me grapes and apple... will not list mango ..

Comment: Well, maybe this can help http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1796-Javascript-Array-Methods-Unshift-Shift-Push-And-Pop-.htm